# Query LDAP with curl

Tags: curl, ldap

I try to query ldap data with curl. I have two request:

```
curl -v -u "cn=adm" 
"ldap://domain.local:389/cn=john123,ou=users,o=merlin,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

This one is working fine, I got john123 information

```
curl -v -u "cn=adm" 
"ldap://domain.local:389/ou=users,o=merlin,dc=domain,dc=com?cn?sub?(cn=john123)"
```

This one always fails but I don't understand why. I follow the rfc: https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/rfc1959.txt

Comment: How does it fail? Similar query works on my Mac with an OpenDJ server.